# オブジェクトのすり抜けに対するアドバイスお願いいたします。

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity3Dにてシーソーの実験をしていたのですが、
画像のように、右側の重いCubeがシーソーをすり抜けてしまいます。
使用しているオブジェクトには全てRigidbodyを設定しており、
Seesawに関しては、X軸回転のみ許可しています。
UseGravity = ON,OFFどちらでの変化ありませんでした。
Mass=1.0f
速度はそれほど早くないとは思いますが、念のために
Collision Detection　は全てContinuousDynamic　にしてあります。
Omori1 Mass=1.0f
Omori2 Mass=1000.0f
全てのオブジェクトには、BoxColliderを有効にしてあります。
※IsTrigger=OFF
原因と対策を教えていただけましたら幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

Unity の物理エンジン（多分 PhysX）の癖でしょうね。以下の対応でましになると思います。

- シーソーを重くする
- TimeScale を小さくする（計算負荷が上がり過ぎるのでおすすめしません）

まだプレビュー版で正式リリースされていませんが、物理エンジンを Havok に切り替えることもできるので、そちらに期待してもいいかもしれません。

1kg と 1t の衝突が物理エンジン的に現実的でないのか、Unity 上ではあまり正しい挙動にも見えませんでした。Unity は「物理シミュレーター」ではなくゲームエンジンなので、物理シミュレーターとして正しい挙動を期待するのも無理な話だと思います。